# Print text from a java class method within a .jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm just experiencing JSP form Java, I'm using a Java *.java class, within this class there's a method that print a String `System.out.println("Message");`, I call this method from index.jsp, the message "Message" appears on the console of the server but not in the index.jsp because `System.out.println();` won't work on a jsp file.
Edit: The question is obvious how to send and show this message in my index.jsp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a JSP, you have an implicit `out` object. Use `out.println()` to print to the web pages.

Additionaly, inside the HTML you can use <%= "Message" %> (or <% myMessage.toString() %> to the same effect

UPDATE:

Either you are in the JSP (or servlet) or you are not. The object that receives the stream to write the HTML is a servlet* (explicit or being compiled from JSP). If you can write from some other class, you need to pass the `out` to that class and use it (you cannot write to the web page with System.out).

Be careful not to pass it to your bussiness logic class, these should be UI agnostic (i.e. they do not have to know that the UI is HTML); it would be bad practice as it would mix internal classes with external output.

Comment: Are they just voting down (lose reputations) for misunderstanding?! SJuan76, I know what are you talking about, these are basics, no one could go somewhere without knowing how to print, right? I can't do `out.println();` because I'm on a .java class right? I've a method on my java class that shows values from an array, so I enter a loop and show the array items by printing `System.out.println("Element");`.

Comment: I believe the downvote is because your question looked like you didn't have bothered to read about the `out` object, which is in the very basics of JSPs.

Comment: I was clear, that what you thought not what I said, but any way thanks for the information you've just provided me :)

Comment: So how to pass the output to the jsp file?

Comment: Either retrieve the array from the JSP and write to out from there, or create a method that accepts a Writer and call it from the JSP (passing the out object)

Comment: It's alright, I returned (`return message;`) the message from the method and I'm done. Thanks dear Juan.
Do you still believe that worth a downvote? ;)